# About c3p0 and hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I write a hibernate.cfg.xml file almost the same from hibernate books like:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">**</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">**</property>

<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_size">30</property>
<property name="c3p0.time_out">1800</property>
<property name="c3p0.max_statement">50</property>
<!--property name="show_sql">true</property-->
<property name="format_sql"> true</property>
```

But this seems actually c3p0 is not used. When I do test to establish 1000 sessions, it tries to establish 1000 connections.

Could anyone please give me some hint about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your configuration file seems that you are missing one key property

```
 <property name="connection.provider_class">
     org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
 </property>
```

Try setting this property and see if this turns things around for you or not.